# Dnn Razor Script Localization

Tags: razor, localization, dotnetnuke

I know how to localize regular DNN modules but I'm not sure where to begin with Razor Scripts hosted in the DNN Razor Host Module.

I keep my localization resx files in a separate assembly so I thought the easiest thing would be to the resources from the Assembly using the ResourceManager but this doesn't seem to tie in well with Dnn's localization framework, since the resources won't be editable in Dnn.

If at all possible I'd like to keep the resource files embedded but I would understand if that was not possible.

Either way, how do I access these resources in a Razor Script file in Dnn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this apporoach, but I'm not sure if it is what you looking for...

```
    @using DotNetNuke.Services.Localization
    @{
        var localResourceFile = "/DesktopModules/RazorModules/RazorHost/Scripts/App_LocalResources/SharedResources.ascx." + Dnn.Portal.CultureCode + ".resx";
        var text = Localization.GetString("pepamaca.Text", localResourceFile);
    }

    <div>@text</div>
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Can you provide an example of how you would use a resource string in the HTML? 
2) So are you saying there's no possibility of keeping these resource files embedded in an external assembly?

Comment: 1 - only you need to add the "@text" inside an html element like a div or p

Comment: 2 - I'm not sure what is your request, if you need to access to another resource file in the DNN only change the Path of the localResourceFile

Comment: thanks for point 1). 
2) I'm referring to accessing Resx files embedded in external custom libraries. The purpose of this is to limit the number of files I have to copy between Dev and Production. If I could I would even like to embed the actual Razor Scripts in an external library but I'd be stuck with the same problem: How to access them in Dnn